# Expiration of NHibernate query cache

Tags: nhibernate, query-cache

Is it possible to configure expiration of NHibernate's query cache?

For second level cache I can do it from `nhibernate.cfg.xml`, but I can't find a way for SQL query cache.

**EDIT:**

```
ICriteria query = CreateCriteria()
                  .Add(Expression.Eq("Email", identifiant))
                  .SetCacheable(true)
                  .SetCacheRegion("X");



 <syscache>
    <cache region="X" expiration="10" priority="1" />
  </syscache>
```

Comment: Francois, because your settings seem to be ok, I've extended my answer of one important setting in the nhibernate.cfg.xml cofniguration. Maybe this would be the missing piece

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can set cache expiration via region. Adjust the query like this:

```
criteria.SetCacheable(true)
    .SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
    .SetCacheRegion("LongTerm");
```

And put similar configuration into web.config file

```
<configSections>
    <section name="syscache" type="NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheSectionHandler, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<syscache>
    <cache region="LongTerm" expiration="180" priority="5" />
    <cache region="ShortTerm" expiration="60" priority="3" />
</syscache>
```

**EDIT**: I am just adding this link [Class-cache not used when getting entity by criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073956/)
To be sure what I mean by *SQL Query cache*. In the linked answer I am explaining that topic

Just for a clarity. The configuration of the NHibernate "session-factory" must contain:

```
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

This switch will make query cache working. More details: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache

Comment: The question was specifically NOT about second level cache.

Comment: What do you mean by term SQL query cache. There is a class cache, which is in a config file declared as: <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>. The query cache is :
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>. And my answer is related to that. The cache of the query (cached criteria result - **query cache**)

Comment: Yes I mean query cache. I made some tests with cache région defined like for the second level cache, but it has no effect (and I didn't down vote)

Comment: Expiration works for me this way. But there could be some caveat with **futures**? Then all queries in "one" future must have the same region! otherwise they are not cached. (The down vote was/and is not there right now)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am using. So, are you saying that after 10 seconds, you cannot see a query in SQL profiler, right? Or the cache is not working at all? Because your setting below the EDIT clause is similar to my

Comment: I wasn't seeing it in SQL profiler. This morning I fully rebuild the solution and it seems ok. I made a test page that call the repository each 100 ms, 500 times, and set expiration to 10 sec, and I see the 5 queries. Thanks for your time.